# image larger than container creates scrollbar on IE and Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position, scrollbar, css-transforms

**Background**

I need to have an image larger than its container. The idea is to give the users the option to add full-width images to content pages, if they want to.

**Problem**

I used `calc(100vw)` with `left: 50%;` and `translateX(-50%)`. This works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. However, IE11 and Edge bring a horizontal scroll bar.

**Code**

HTML

```
<div>
  <img />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}

img {
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: calc(100vw);
}
```

**Fiddle**

Here's an example so you can test and play: https://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/nbmy5mjf/1/

**Question**

How can I remove/hide the scroll bar from IE and Edge?

I thought this happened due to the way the image's position is being calculated. However, I noticed that Firefox and Chrome also show a scroll bar if I remove the `display: block;` from the image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
body {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

or just:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden
}
```

and drop the `calc()` it isn't doing anything there.

#### Snippet

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden
}
div {
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}
img {
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://randomrab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/thumpimage.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: The `calc()` isn't doing anything on the example, but I need it on my final code. The `overflow-x` is a good idea, I will test the implications of this and see if it works as expected in all browsers. Thank you for your reply.